# Error running selenium test on ubuntu

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, chromedriver

I'm having trouble running a selenium test on ubuntu, but everything works fine on my windows system. I'm using a mocha test suite, and am using [selenium-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) to run the selenium test written in javascript. The error I get is:

```
    1) Register a new account [1]
       "before all" hook: ret:
     Error: Server terminated early with status 1
      at earlyTermination.catch.e (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:252:52)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
      at Function.createSession (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
      at Function.createSession (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
      at createDriver (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
      at Builder.build (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:642:16)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/UI/create_recent_users.js:82:10)
      at runTest (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:159:14)
      at /home/deniz/Desktop/selenium/jaguar/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:184:16
      at new ManagedPromise (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1077:7)
      at controlFlowExecute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:183:14)
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
      at asyncRun (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2974:25)
      at /home/deniz/Desktop/selenium/jaguar/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
      at <anonymous>
  From: Task: Register a new account [1] "before all" hook: ret
      at Context.ret (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:182:10)
```

I'm not really sure whats going on. I believe its got something to do with chrome/the chrome driver but I dont know where to go from here. The [chrome driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver) I am using is also being installed from a node package.

Comment: I vaguely remember on Ubuntu, you need a different version of Chrome.

Comment: @YuZhang Thanks turns out the version of chrome I had on ubuntu wasn't compatible with the chromedriver version I'm using

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Yu Zhang I was having compatibility issues with the chrome version I was running and the chrome driver.

I ended up just updating both my driver and the version of chrome I was using. 
The specific compatibilities can be seen on the official [chrome driver download page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)